# Запрос к базе данных через JDBC. PostgresSQL

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc

Есть java программа и таблица `students` в базе данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Программа получает данные столбцов из таблицы в базе данных следующим образом:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM table_name";
Statement statement = statement.getConnection().createStatement(); 
ResultSet resultSet;
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);
resultSet.getInt(1);
resultSet.getInt(2);
```

и т. д.

А как можно получить список всех имеющихся таблиц в базе данных **через** приложение (через консоль - `\d`)?
Какие использовать методы для выполнение запросов в приложении на подобии:

```
/* Получение id студентов с фамилией Suvorov */
SELECT student_id FROM students WHERE last_name = 'Suvorov';
```

Comment: *как можно получить список **всех имеющихся таблиц** в базе данных* ответ зависит от конкретной СУБД. Подавляющее большинство поддерживает системные представления INFORMATION_SCHEMA - можно через них.

Answer (score 0):

**Вопросы решены** Для того, что я хотел - нужно использовать Metadata и несколько других классов из JDBC.